# Joi validate one of two schemas

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

I have a simple object with few fields that I would like to validate. I wish to allow or a specific validation schema or that **all** of the properties have empty values

I created the following two schemas:

```
 const nonEmptyUserInfoValidationSchema = Joi.object({
    url: Joi.string().uri().required(),
    username: Joi.string().required().min(usernameMinLength),
    password: Joi.string().required().min(passwordMinLength),
});

const emptyUserInfoValidationSchema = Joi.object({
    url: Joi.string().empty().required(),
    username: Joi.string().empty().required(),
    password: Joi.string().empty().required(),
});
```

I wish to create schema that validates if `emptyUserInfoValidationSchema` or `nonEmptyUserInfoValidationSchema` is applied but I can't figure out how to do it, any suggestions?

allowed:

```
{url:"http://some.url", username:"some username", password:"some password"}
{url:"", username:"", password:""}
```

not allowed:

```
{url:"http://some.url",  username:"", password:""}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I finally found what I was looking for `joi.alternatives`:

```
export const ansibleInfoValidationSchema = Joi.alternatives(emptyUserInfoValidationSchema , nonEmptyUserInfoValidationSchema );
```

seems to do the trick

Comment: what if one of the objects matches, I want to ignore the other schema and move to the next data from an array? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658952/joi-validations-if-object-matches-the-schema-validate-against-it-from-multiple

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you can use the **when** condition in Joi

```
var schema = Joi.object({
  url : Joi.any().when('username',{
    is: Joi.empty(),
    then: Joi.empty().required(),
    otherwise: Joi.string().required()
  }),
  username: Joi.when('password',{
    is: Joi.empty(),
    then: Joi.empty(),
    otherwise: Joi.string().required().min(usernameMinLength)
  })
});
```

here's a link to when docs [Joi When Condtion](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.5.0#anywhencondition-options)

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I was looking for, since it is almost impossible to do with large objects (and not covering all of the edge cases even now with a simple object).

Answer (score 0):

You use the `.keys().and()` to specify peers. This means that none of the fields specified in the `.and()` will exist without each other. Hence should be used as so:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  url: Joi.string().uri(),
  username: Joi.string().min(usernameMinLength),
  password: Joi.string().min(passwordMinLength)
}).keys().and('url', 'username', 'password');
```

Comment: You usually want to explain what your code is doing, and why it should work, instead of just posting the code.